# JQTouch loading external html page

Tags: iphone, ajax, jqtouch

Do we need to have all pages inside divs in one html page?
In case of my website I would need to create a huge file to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that no, you do not. In your link tags, instead of typing:

```
<a id="#linkTo">Link!</a>
```

You would type

```
<a href="link/to/content">Link!</a>
```

Your content would have to be an html snippet instead of a fully baked web page. You can look at the demos to see how this is done.